# Conservation in finite element codes

Tags: finite-element, conservation

Typical finite volume methods are conservative, because fluxes (of e.g., mass or energy) are always between neighboring cells. Is the same generally true for finite element codes? Do I correctly assume that implicit time stepping would then be 'globally' conservative, except for flows through the domain boundaries?

Background information: The reason I'm asking is that colleagues who use the [plasma module](https://www.comsol.com/plasma-module) of Comsol do not observe charge conservation in their simulations. The equations are of the following form:
$$\partial_t n_1 + \nabla \cdot \vec{f} = S \, n_1\\
\partial_t n_2 = S \, n_1,$$
where $\vec{f}$ and $S$ non-linearly depend on other variables. The quantity $\int n_2 - n_1 dV$ is not conserved, but the conservation error shrinks for smaller time steps. I believe that this module internally works with $log(n)$ instead of $n$, where $n$ is the density, to avoid certain numerical problems.

Comment: finite element discretizations are, in general, non-conservative - as explained [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19458/the-meaning-of-conservative-discretization-in-galerkin-fem-and-discontinuous-gal).

Comment: Do you mean the second answer (which I don't really understand)? The first answer addresses stability.